# Can't reset Drupal admin password

Tags: drupal-7

I need to reset my Drupal site's admin password and I can't user the email reset because the admin email doesn't exist.

I followed the directions here: http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/reset-your-drupal-admin-password/

I ran the SQL: UPDATE dr_users SET pass = md5('newpassword') WHERE uid = 1; - no luck

I also tried entering a password into the users table manually in plain text. - no luck

At this point I'm not sure what the problem is.

The only thing I can think of, and I can't see why this would be it, is that I have a browser open with Admin logged in using the old password. This seems to be a hint to my problem as I would expect that on page refresh I would get logged out as the password has now changed.

Comment: can you update the admin email via mysql, then have drupal email you the password reset?  what's the output from SQL `SELECT * FROM dr_users WHERE uid = 1;` ?

Comment: Joe, since you answered in a comment, I don't see a way to mark the answer which (I'm new to stackoverflow) I believes give you credit.

Comment: ok i will post it as an answer, thank you and glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to update the admin email via mysql, then have drupal email you the password reset.
To see what you have now, you could look at the output from SQL

```
SELECT * FROM dr_users WHERE uid = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy!

With the access to the table "users" (i.e. this table can have a prefix that you have already mentioned during the installation part, so yourPrefix_ can be your project's name as mywebsitename_, and in this case you'll have mywebsitename_users) in your database via PhpMyAdmin for example.

You should alter the "pass" column associated with the "uid" column with the value 1 (i.e 1 for the admin user account).

As the encrypted value for the password:  Admin_12345  is =>

$S$DifCVXg9tNtHadziyyQJQVLAaZzW5EgS6OjR56D.mk8MpNQs1II2

You can accede to your admin account after replacing the old hashed password value stored in your database that you have totally forgotten.

Don't forget to change the password: Admin_12345 after you accede to your account ;)